# How to create my custom vim snippets?

Tags: vim, plugins, code-snippets

I want to create some snippets when writting c++.
for example:
create a file, cpp.snippets.

```
priority -1
snippet exam
This is an example!
endsnippet
```

and put it in ~/.vim/my-snippets/snippets/.
then, add following statement in ~/.vimrc:

```
set runtimepath+=~/.vim/my-snippets/
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir='~/.vim/my-snippets/'
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["snippets"]
```

But it not work, how can i fix it ?

Comment: Let's start at the beginning: Do you have UltiSnips? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, I have UltiSnips, and it work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

UltiSnips plugin includes detailed documentation. Have you read the following help page?

```
:help UltiSnips-snippet-search-path
```

**Update:**

One of the things that was obvious when I read that help section was that in UltiSnips the name "snippets" can't be used in `g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories` because it is reserved for snipMate compatible snippets. This does not happen in the link shared in the comment below, where the name "my-snippets" is used instead.

I do not use UltiSnips, but from the documentation I would suggest the following approach:

1. Do not set `g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir` nor `g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories`.
2. Keep the `runtimepath+=` configuration.
3. Create the following directory: `~/.vim/my-snippets/UltiSnips`.
4. Place the personal snippets under this new directory.

Reasoning:

- By default UltiSnips searches for all `UltiSnips` directories under your runtime paths, so no configuration is required if this name is used.
- Although the `runtime` setting is required for personal snippets, this configuration is automatically maintained if a plugin manager is used.
- The last point allows the installation of vim plugins that contain snippets. For example, [this](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) plugin contains various snippets for both snipMate and UltiSnips, including C++.

Comment: Yes, I have. But, maybe i misunderstand its means.
anyway, I reference this web, https://www.physik.uni-leipzig.de/~marenz/index.cgi/blog/ , and fixed my problem.
And thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Kai7 I've updated my answer because it was not obvious from your comment if you understood what was wrong in your original configuration. I also provided an alternative and simpler approach to solve your  problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using the `sirver/ultisnips` plugin (UltiSnips) the correct way to do this is simply run the `:UltiSnipsEdit` command which opens up a custom snippets file for the current language / filetype.

Comment: Thank you! This is the most sensible answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had so much grief with this. Here is an answer for future reference for those of you who do not want to suffer headaches.

I have a shared `.vimrc` served on a samba share. *Both Windows gViM and ViM use this file.*

## Relevant Part of .vimrc for Windows

I have a samba share mounted under `L:`. Note that I actually had to use POSIX for the path, not Windows backslashes `\` despite being a path *for* Windows.

```
if has('win32') || has('win64') "If gVim under Windows"
    let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["L:/.vim/custom_snippets"]
endif
```

## Relevant Part of .vimrc for Unix

My terminal opens `xterm-256color` for more colors, but you could exchange that with `xterm`. Here the path can expand `~` correctly, since this is the real home directory where my ``.vim` lives.

```
if $TERM == "xterm-256color"
  let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["~/.vim/custom_snippets"]
endif
```

## Finishing Touches to Load custom_snippets

You don't need any! The following changes are **NOT** necessary:

```
"let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["custom_snippets"]
"let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir="~/.vim/snippets_custom/"
```

However, **Putty does not pass the tab key or control key** properly it seems, despite all paths working fine. *I tested the paths with `:UltiSnipsEdit` while in a file type environment `set ft=tex` and it took me to `~/.vim/snippets_custom/tex.snippets`* as it should (both in gvim on Windows and from my unix console).

Perhaps Useful for enabling  in Putty

- Patch: [Creating a ctrl+tab keybinding in PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736004/creating-a-ctrltab-keybinding-in-putty)
- [How to solve the collision of TAB key mapping of `UltiSnips` plugin in the Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622566/how-to-solve-the-collision-of-tab-key-mapping-of-ultisnips-plugin-in-the-vim)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53581/sending-function-keys-f1-f12-over-ssh